# Dump Map<String,Object> yaml obj to local file without line breaks

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I have a `Map<String, Object> object`, which is obtained from:

```java
new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml().load(someStr)
```

I want to dump object to a local file, when I use:

```java
new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().writeValue(new File(filePath), object)
```

I got a proper file, but if some string filed in that object is too long. It broke at multiple lines, and was added line breaks, like this:

```sql
SELECT materialid, accountid, device_type, material_type, content
  FROM cpc01.material_style_##
```

What should I do to make `ObjectMapper` to dump string field into one line instead of multiple lines?

Comment: Why are you using SnakeYAML for loading but Jackson for writing? SnakeYAML has [an option](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.yaml/snakeyaml/latest/org/yaml/snakeyaml/DumperOptions.html#setSplitLines(boolean)) for disabling line breaks, I don't know whether it's settable over the Jackson API.

Comment: @flyx Thanks, it works  by using SnakeYaml.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @flyx, using SnakeYaml can handle it, my code is as below:

```
DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
options.setSplitLines(false); // remove the line breaks
options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK); // remove quotes
options.setIndent(2);
options.setPrettyFlow(true); // remove curly brackets
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
// omit some code
yaml.dump(finalYamlMap, new FileWriter(fileName));
```